# What spells/powers can a war wizard use?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

I'm picking back up the *Sword of Truth* books and I recall that Richard Rahl as a war wizard was able to do all sorts of magic by instinct when the need arose.

However, I don't recall if there was ever a real defined concept of what sort of powers and spells (using the term loosely, as they are done by instinct) could be used. He used healing magic a few times and he seemed to be able to enhance his archery skills. He also found a book he needed in a giant library and did some other minor stuff.

But could Richard use Wizard's Fire or cast a web to hide something? Essentially, I'm wondering if he could theoretically cast any power or spell that another wizard could or if there was a group of powers he tended to be limited to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

War Wizards have the gift for both additive and subtractive magic. This is in contrast to Zed, who only had the gift for additive magic, and Darken Rahl, who had the gift for additive magic and the calling for subtractive magic.

Anything was within Richard's capacity. When he visited the Temple of the Winds he learned how to do pretty much everything, however that knowledge was lost to him when he chose to leave. Most of the series he doesn't have any wizarding training, subsequently he makes webs, wizards fire, and other things instinctually.

Comment: Which book did he first make wizard's fire?

Comment: With the assistance of Nathan Rahl he made wizard's fire in Stone of Tears.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I only recall him creating the normal sort of fire.

Comment: I just found the chapter and Nathan Rahl says "That [fire I helped you create] was to Wizard's Fire what an annoyed moth is to an enraged bull." So I take it he could do Wizard's Fire and more.

Comment: @Zoredache I consider any artificial fire created by magic to be wizard's fire.

Comment: @JackBNimble well the quote Thunderforge added would seem to indicate you are wrong in the context of this series.  Many of the attributes of 'wizards fire' as described in the series make it sound more like napalm then ordinary fire.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Rahl is a war wizard war wizards have the capacity to wield the sword of truth without becoming whatever Samuel is so technically speaking with the help of other war wizards or years of practice Richard could have done anything Nicci could have done. However Richards gift is bonded with the sword of truth and it was bonded well before his gift awakened (it awakened in stone of tears after darken rahl was killed)
This means that Richards and the swords "gift" are bonded making his gift run with the elements of the sword

Comment: I haven't read the latest few books, but I don't recall anything saying that a true Seeker must be a War Wizard. In fact, Zedd seemed pretty surprised to find that Richard was one, and yet had no issues with naming him a true Seeker. Also, Rahl was killed at the end of Wizards First Rule, not Stone of Tears.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to wield the sword of truth isn't a war wizard thing - in fact there's no reference that any of the previous seekers were wizards - the seeker just has to be the right TYPE of person. A person who can love and hate - thus turning the sword white.

Comment: I think that this would be better as a comment, since this doesn't really answer the question, which was about the magic itself, rather than the Sword of Truth.

Comment: Agreed but at the time I didn't have the rights to comment :(